# Is storing a private key possible to be secure?

Tags: java, ssl, public-key-encryption, private-key, jks

This question is about a project of mine. I have a server-side application running on my Raspberry Pi, while the client-side application is supposed to be distributed on all my other devices. The following exzerpt is showing the code of the client-side.

I've been digging the Internet and what I have gathered is that in the end there no 100% safe way to store a private key. However, it is considered good practice to safe all keys in a KeyStore. The following is my solution to it, but my problem is: **the KeyStore-file**, `client.jks`, **lies inside the JAR, together with the hardcoded password**. `client.jks` contains the server-side's public key and the client-side's private key.

```
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE), PASSWORD.toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, PASSWORD.toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

        SSLSocket connection = (SSLSocket) sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket("localhost", 6789);
        System.out.println("Connection successful!");
```

The Strings `KEYSTORE` and `PASSWORD` contain the KeyStore-file and the password, both hardcoded.
Is this really the best practice or am I missing something? Is the new `SecureRandom` object created for every connection enough to make the connection safe?

Best regards and thank you for your answers!

Comment: `FileInputStream` can't access a jar entry; if you do want the jks in the jar you need `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`, see about a thousand existing Qs on that topic. Whether you want a client-key and password(s) in the jar depends on what security goals you are trying to achieve against what threat model, which your Q doesn't say a word about. Are you worried about people who steal a copy of your app or subvert a machine containing it connecting to your server? How about people who don't? Do you know and care which user or machine is which?

Comment: If the password to the keystore is in your code, this has basically the same security level as an unprotected keystore, since everybody with access to the jar file can extract the keystore password and thus access client's private key. As noted by @dave_thompson_085, what you need depends on your threat scenario. In general, every method trying to protect key material distributed by an application is mostly snake oil.